# Evaluating the following integral:

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

I am trying to evaluate this integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\cos(x)}{1+x^{2}}dx$$

My attempt:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{(x+i)(x-i)}dx=1/2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{(x+i)(x-i)}dx$$

Where do I go from here? My teacher told me that I need $$\oint \frac{e^{iz}}{(z+i)(z-i)}dz$$ but I don't understand how we go from $$1/2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{(x+i)(x-i)}dx$$ to $$\oint \frac{e^{iz}}{(z+i)(z-i)}dz$$

Thanks

Comment: Using displaystyle in title, especially combined with the enlarged font size, is highly depreciated.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I fixed it and will not do it again in the future.

Comment: You don't need to go from $\cos(x)$ to $e^{iz}$. Compute the $e^{iz}$ integral and take the real part.

Comment: See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration#Example_.28II.29_.E2.80.93_Cauchy_distribution

Comment: More more exactly use $\ \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{iz}}{1+z^2} dz=\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{e^{iz}}{1+z^2} dz+\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{iz}}{1+z^2} dz=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{1+z^2} dz$ (set $x:=-z$ over $(-\infty,0)$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define

$$f(z):=\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\;,\;\;C_R:=[-R,R]\cup\gamma_R:=\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;|z|=R\;,\;\text{Im}(z)\ge 0\}\;,\;\;\Bbb R\ni R>>0$$

The only (simple, BTW) pole of $\,f\,$ inclosed by the above closed curve is $\,z=i\,$ , and

$$\text{Res}(f)_{z=i}\lim_{z\to i}(z-i)f(z)=\frac{e^{-1}}{2i}$$

So by Cauchy's Theorem:

$$2\pi i\,\text{Res}(f)_{z=i}=\frac\pi e=\oint\limits_{C_R}f(z)\,dz=\int\limits_{-R}^R\frac{e^{ix}}{x^2+1}+\int\limits_{\gamma_R}f(z)\,dz$$

But the Evaluation theorem gives (with $\;z=x+iy\,$):

$$\left|\int\limits_{\gamma_R}f(z)\,dz\;\right|\le\max_{|z|=R}\frac{e^{-y}}{R^2-1}R\pi\xrightarrow[R\to\infty]{}0$$

so we get

$$\frac\pi e=\lim_{R\to\infty}\oint\limits_{C_R}f(z)\,dz=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos x+i\sin x}{x^2+1}dx$$

Now just compare real-imaginary parts and using the real one is an even function get the result $\;\displaystyle{\frac\pi{2e}}\,$